# Name for a complete graph with a perfect matching removed?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

A [crown graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_graph) is a graph formed by taking $K_{n,n}$ and removing a perfect matching. Is there a name for a complete graph $K_{2n}$ from which a perfect matching has been removed? This came up in the context of a family of graphs I encountered, and I'm not sure whether this is a well-studied category of graphs. Google isn't turning up helpful results for queries like "complete graph minus perfect matching" or "clique with perfect matching removed."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope "The 1-skeleton of a n-dimensional cross-polytope is a Turán graph T(2n, n)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's a special case of a Turán graph, because it's the complete $n$-partite graph $K_{2,2,2,\dots,2,2}$.

This particular Turán graph is also known as a **cocktail party graph**, representing the number of handshakes that occur if $n$ couples go to a cocktail party and everyone shakes hands with everyone they meet there (but not with their partner).